# MPXJ - getting task_type from Primavera .XER file

Tags: mpxj, primavera

I've been using MPXJ (.net v4.7.3) to read info from a Primavera .XER file.

It's been going really well but I am having trouble finding the property task_type (Activity Type)

The .XER file has the property and the values (TT_FinMile, TT_Mile, TT_LOE..etc) but after I have read in the file and am iterating through the tasks, I can't find any property of the net.sf.mpxj.Task class that holds that info.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just updated MPXJ to read the task_type attribute from an XER file and store it in the TEXT2 attribute of the task in MPXJ. You can use this now if you build a version of MPXJ from the code in Git, or if you don't mind waiting it will be available in the next release version of MPXJ (which will have a version > 4.7.3).